# How to call startActivityForResult from ActivityGroup

Tags: android, tabwidget, activitygroup, start-activity

I am using tab widget and each tab belong to a activity group. An activity group has several sub activities.The sub activites are added to the activity group via `LocalActivityManager.startActivitY` from activity group but now i want to use startActivityForResult from instead of startActivity. Can someone help me to accomplish that as `LocalActivityManager` class does not have`startActivityForResult` method..

Answer (score 0):

@Sabya i had been there in the same situation few weeks past. And i have found from my side that there is no way to use startActivityForResult in ActivityGroup. So i found some hacking type of technique to get out of this. First create a static variable of the result you want from startActivityforResult.After doing this,intent to a transparent Activity,in which you doing all those stuff of activityforResult.After getting value you set the value of the static variable that you created in the TabClass,After then finish the transparent Activity